# Access local file shares and devices through router

Tags: networking, router

Network Diagram:

[image]

I'm at my home office, and work has provided me with a router(B) that tunnels outbound traffic through an OpenVPN tunnel, this allows a desk phone and my computer to access work shares etc. - However, I have several local services on the upper subnet, such as printers and other devices that are now unreachable behind router b. When configuring router B I've allowed traffic to access wan and devices in the upper subnet are pingable, but I'm unable to configure SMB: shares, or locate printers via bonjour etc.

I've tried to port forward smb share ports, but I don't think this is the correct way.

Router B WAN port has IP assigned by DHCP of Router A
Not all traffic is routed through OPEN VPN, devices on 192.168.1.0/24 are pingable from 192.168.8.0/24 as well as devices on 192.168.100.0/24 but I'm not able to connect to my services on 192.168.1.0/24 from 192.168.8.0/24'

I've tried searching for other questions multiple times, but it is clogged with people trying to make their SMB shares or services available on the internet. That's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does [this article](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/reach-openvpn-clients-directly-from-a-private-network/) about using routing help?

Comment: So the devices are pingable between subnets, but services are not reachable?   I would go install Nmap and scan from each host to each other host to see what (if any) services are available from the perspective of each host.     Is there a good reason why you would put your printer on a separate subnet?  My understanding of how Bonjour works is the device has to be on the same subnet unless you configure multicast routing between the two subnets, or use a Bonjour proxy or Unicast DNS Service Discovery.

Comment: here is a link to download nmap https://nmap.org/download

Comment: Also, let me know if you need any help scanning with nmap.  There is a GUI (Zenmap) that will install on Windows which makes using nmap much easier.   The ports I would expect to see open, closed or filtered are 135/tcp (msrpc), 139/tcp (netbios-ssn), 445/tcp (microsoft-ds) for SMB.   Not sure what protocol you are using for your printer

Answer (score 0):

Direct SMB access (by IP address) only needs regular routing (TCP); if `ping ip` works, `\\ip` should also work.

Bonjour (mDNS) does not work across subnets. You can make it work by running Avahi-daemon in "reflector" mode on a machine that's on both subnets (e.g. a router; I think OpenWRT has its own mDNS reflector as well), but not by using regular IP routing – not even if you enable multicast routing. (Most mDNS implementations send packets with TTL of 1, meaning they won't get routed no matter what.)

The same goes for Windows' WS-Discovery as well as the historical NetBIOS discovery; they're limited to a single subnet.

Comment: glad someone else was able to confirm that bonjour does not work across subnets.